# What does "Open Shoot" mean?

Tags: terminology, photography-basics

What does an "open shoot" mean for a photography class/course? Does it mean to take pictures of anything you like?

- My reasonable explanation for what my question is that I'm confused and don't understand what the photography term “open shoot” means. Was wondering if anyone would be able to help.
- I've looked it up on Google but it wasn't enough to solve my problem.
- I spelt it correctly if anyone was wondering. It's Open Shoot not OpenShoot or Open Shot.

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption is correct; an "Open Shoot" simply means that there is not a particular assigned subject. The word "open" in [this context](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/open) means *not restricted*.

An assigned subject in a photography course could be something general like nature or street photography or something specific like architectural details, abstract art, or the color red. Instead, with an Open Shoot, you can take photos of anything you like.

When I took a photography class in Vancouver, Canada, Open Shoot was used in this manner. Here is a [different photography class](http://personal.tcc.on.ca/users/vercruyssen/web/photographyfocuscourse.htm) in Vancouver and a [camera club](http://www.cscc.us/csccnew/HTML%20webpages/competition.htm) in Florida that define it in the same way, too.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share a source.

Comment: @MrUpsidown It is a pretty common term, at least in North America. Added sources, as requested.